# Seg-fault on some runs and not on others (with the same input file)

Tags: c++

I'm a CS student taking a c++ class. I have an odd error, where the program sometimes runs a seg fault on the same input (and sometimes not). I'm very confused about what may be happening.
Does anyone have any ideas?
My post is in this order: my code, the input file, the output (3 different outputs using the same input).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct Class {
    std::string name;
    double totalWork;
    double totalLearned;
    bool hasVisited;
    Class* neighbors;
    Class* previousClass;
};

void searchClassOne(int indexCurrent, int indexNeighbor, int numClasses, double maxWork, 
                    double& maxLearning, Class* classes)
{
    if(indexCurrent == numClasses - 1)  return;

    if(indexNeighbor == numClasses - 2) {
        indexNeighbor = 0;
        indexCurrent++;
    }

    int totalWork = classes[indexCurrent].totalWork +         
        classes[indexCurrent].neighbors[indexNeighbor].totalWork;

    int totalLearning = classes[indexCurrent].totalLearned +     
        classes[indexCurrent].neighbors[indexNeighbor].totalLearned;

    if(totalLearning > maxLearning && totalWork < maxWork)  maxLearning = totalLearning;

    indexNeighbor++;

    searchClassOne(indexCurrent, indexNeighbor, numClasses, maxWork, maxLearning, classes);

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string fileName = argv[1];

    std::ifstream ifile(fileName);

    int numClasses = 0, maxWork = 0;

    ifile >> numClasses >> maxWork;

    std::string dummy;
    getline(ifile, dummy);

    Class* classes = new Class[numClasses];

    for(int index = 0; index < numClasses; index++) {
        classes[index].neighbors = new Class[numClasses - 1];
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < numClasses; index++) {
        classes[index].name = "";
        classes[index].totalWork = 0.0;
        classes[index].totalLearned = 0.0;
        classes[index].hasVisited = false;
    }

    int classNum = 0;

    std::cout << "CHECK 1" << std::endl;

    while(classNum < numClasses) {
        ifile >> classes[classNum].name;
        ifile >> classes[classNum].totalWork;
        ifile >> classes[classNum].totalLearned;

        std::string dummyTwo;
        getline(ifile, dummyTwo);

        classNum++;
    }

    std::cout << "CHECK 2" << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        std::cout << "CHECK 3 + " << i << std::endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < numClasses; j++) {
            std::cout << "CHECK 4 + " << j << std::endl;
            if(classes[i].name != classes[j].name)
                classes[i].neighbors[j] = classes[j];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "CHECK 5" << std::endl;

    double maxLearning = 0;

    searchClassOne(0, 0, numClasses, maxWork, maxLearning, classes);

    std::cout << "Maximum learning: " << maxLearning << std::endl;

    delete [] classes;
    classes = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Input file reads:

```
4 3.14159
CSCI104 3.001 10.0
CSCI170 2.41       8.0
ENGR102  0.10 0.36
CSCI280    0.66 2.15
```

Output reads (multiple):

```
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro-2:hw2 Rafael$ ./hw2q6 hw2q6.txt
CHECK 1
CHECK 2
CHECK 3 + 0
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 1
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 2
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 3
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 5
Maximum learning: 8
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro-2:hw2 Rafael$ ./hw2q6 hw2q6.txt
CHECK 1
CHECK 2
CHECK 3 + 0
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 1
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
Segmentation fault: 11
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro-2:hw2 Rafael$ ./hw2q6 hw2q6.txt
CHECK 1
CHECK 2
CHECK 3 + 0
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 1
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 2
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 3
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 5
Maximum learning: 8
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro-2:hw2 Rafael$ ./hw2q6 hw2q6.txt
CHECK 1
CHECK 2
CHECK 3 + 0
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
CHECK 3 + 1
CHECK 4 + 0
CHECK 4 + 1
CHECK 4 + 2
CHECK 4 + 3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger, see which line it faults at.  Start at the beginning, see where your assumptions become invalidated.

Comment: Clever, you parse "4 3" into numClasses and maxWork and then discard the remainder ".14159" using getline(). I'd suggest you use a float for maxWork instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at this line:

```
classes[i].neighbors[j] = classes[j];
```

What is the maximum value of `j`? What is the size of `neighbors`?

Edit: This is what I meant by an extra index variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
    std::cout << "CHECK 3 + " << i << std::endl;
    int neighborIndex = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numClasses; j++) {
        std::cout << "CHECK 4 + " << j << std::endl;
        if(classes[i].name != classes[j].name) {
            classes[i].neighbors[neighborIndex] = classes[j];
            neighborIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change it to numClasses - 1, won't the line: classes[i].name != classes[j].name not work because i iterates to a value one more than j?

Comment: That's right. To set up the neighbors how you want to, it is probably easiest to have three variables. The `i` and `j` as you currently have them and another counter for the neighbor index. If you only increment the neighbor index when the names don't match, then it won't go out of bounds.

Comment: Another nested for loop? I'm not sure i'm following 100 percent... sorry. I'm still learning ><

Comment: Not another loop, just another counter. I have updated my answer with example code.